# Writing a String from Java to Excel using fileWriter

Tags: java, excel, filewriter

I am trying to write a string to excel from a java api.  However when i try and write to the excel Sheet one of my fields get messed up and i am unsure as to the cause.

My String is made up of multiple parts, FirstName, SurName Address, Tell Number.

There are all wrapped up in there own person object.  For the toString i concatinate all the items together for output.

However when i check in the csv the tell number is distorted.  it will have changed from 12345678901234567 -> 12345678901234500  Added in zero as the last 2 numbers.

I have other numbers in my sheet that are not a long that get output fine, but can anyone tell me what might be the issue here, the number in the toString is fine, so the java api has not manipuated it.  It appears to be either an Excel problem or a problem with the FileWriter perhaps, although i find this odd as the address is far longer than 17 chars??

Any advice greatly appreciated

Comment: why not use an api like jExcel?

Comment: Might it be that the code output strings quoted, and numbers not? Then a bug might be additionally outputting 00, maybe for the two quotes. Especially the magic numbers 17 and 15 I would search in the code too.